# How to handle click below the last item in ListView?

Tags: android, listview, click, handle

I have a listView with some items. How to handle click on the area "A" below the last item in ListView?
*-------------------------*

item1

*-------------------------*

item2

*-------------------------*

item3

*-------------------------*

area A

*-------------------------*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#000000">
    <ListView 
        android:id="@+id/lvMainLeft" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
        style="@style/list_view">
    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: There shouldn't be any area since your ListView's layout_height is set to fill_parent.

Comment: what you want to do onClick of that area? Is it footer of your listView?

Comment: I have two lists. When I click on the one that I want to change the color of the active list.
When I click on the item that is no problem. But the list is incomplete, and clicking on an empty area also want to change the color.

Comment: Did you find solution for this problem?